# natural characteristics of insects used as human disease model

Tags: entomology, animal-models

In this paper [[1](http://www.pnas.org/content/114/36/9653.long)], the author found that the autism-related genes are conserved between honey bee and human. Thus, this paper providing a means to further explore sociobiology theory. In my opinion, the honey bee have the potential to be developed into an model for human autism disease.

My question is: what other examples in insect like this in honey bee that the model species itself has some characteristics, which could be used as model system for some human disease studies?

Thank you!

[1] Shpigler HY, Saul MC, Corona F, Block L, Cash Ahmed A, Zhao SD, Robinson GE: [Deep evolutionary conservation of autism-related genes](http://www.pnas.org/content/114/36/9653.long). Proc Natl Acad Sci U S A 2017.